# Using Office UI Fabric React components in ScriptLab

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, officedev, scriptlab

In a simple Test Web App I was able to create a UI Fabric React output by using imports like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
```

and rendering in HTML

```
<DefaultButton>Default UI Fabric Button</DefaultButton>
```

Is it possible to use this also in **ScriptLab**?

I see in the Libraries Tab these css items, but I believe these are the UI Fabric Core components, while I'd like to include the UI Fabric React components in ScriptLab.